# Cut string by value in dolar in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
Medical services provided by members of regulated professions, 
Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 2.000,00 , Dr. James Silva
with value of  $ 5.000,00 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6.500,00
```

<sub>(line breaks only inserted for readability)</sub>

How I can identify the values in dolar, $ 2.000,00, $ 5.000,00 e $ 6.500,00 , and cute a string like this:

```
Part 1:  Medical services provided by members of regulated professions, Dr. Rachel G. Barry with value of  $ 2.000,00

Part 2: Dr. James Silva with value of  $ 5.000,00 

Part 3: Dr. Joey House with value of  $ 6.500,00
```

I can use a regex to find a value in dolar, but how I cut the previous sentence?

Comment: You can use regex expressions to find a pattern that starts with a $ and followed by numbers,commas a dots.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I can use a regex to find a value in dolar, but how I cut the previous sentence?

Comment: there alway be same format $ 2,000.00, $ 5,000.00 e $ 6,500.00 that means .00??

Comment: **preg_split**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: to cut the previous sentence you can use explode like this -> $temp=explode("$",$yourString);

Comment: @KrishnaGupta is the format, equivalent to $ 2000,00 , $ 5000,00 ...

Comment: for your reference: $str_temp = trim(str_replace(array(","),"",$str)); //$str is whole string.
 $temp = explode("$",$str_temp); 
 $value1 = explode(" ",$temp[1])[1];
 $value2 = explode(" ",$temp[2])[1];
 print_r($value1);
 print_r($value2);

Comment: that means there will be ',00' in amount excepting anything else (',70', ',90').. m i right?? @Bia

Comment: @KrishnaGupta exactly

Answer (score 1):

Hello i have one solution but only work for this string but you can do like this.

```
<?php 
$str = "Medical services provided by members of regulated professions,  Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 2,000.00, Dr. James Silva with value of  $ 5,000.00 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6,500.00";
$arr = @explode(".00", $str);
echo $arr[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo str_replace(", ","", $arr[1]);
echo "<br/>";
echo str_replace("and","", $arr[2]);
?>
```

Comment: but i need to any string, like this: Medical services provided by members of regulated professions,  Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 4,000.12, Dr. James Silva with value of  $ 6,000.90 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6,500.00

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/(\$ ([0-9\.]+))/', $string, $matches);
```

Here I assume $string is the text string

And $matches will contain the array of output

Further you can try like this : (As per your messages)

```
$string = preg_replace("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", ',', $string);
$pieces = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: Output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => $ 2.000 [1] => $ 5.000 [2] => $ 6.500 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => $ 2.000 [1] => $ 5.000 [2] => $ 6.500 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2.000 [1] => 5.000 [2] => 6.500 ) ), but i want the rest of sentence too.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? you need digits and rest of the content too ?

Comment: Yes, like this: Part 1:  Medical services provided by members of regulated professions, Dr. Rachel G. Barry with value of  $ 2.000,00

Part 2: Dr. James Silva with value of  $ 5.000,00 

Part 3: Dr. Joey House with value of  $ 6.500,00

Comment: Your answer is very good, i get this: Array ( [0] => Medical services provided by members of regulated professions [1] => Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 2.000 [2] => 00 [3] => Dr. James Silva with value of $ 5.000 [4] => 00 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6.500 [5] => 00 )

Comment: Is there a way to get the value complete like this:  [1] => Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 2.000,00, include de ,00?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this solution or simply explode to break the sentence. You can find the reference below.

```
<?php
    $str = "Medical services provided by members of regulated professions, Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 2,000.00, Dr. James Silva with value of  $ 5,000.00 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6,500.00";
    $str_temp = trim(str_replace(array(","),"",$str));
    $temp = explode("$",$str_temp); 
    $value1 = explode(" ",$temp[1])[1]; 
    //$name1 = explode(" with",explode("Dr.",$temp[0])[1]);
    $value2 = explode(" ",$temp[2])[1];
    //$name2 = explode(" with",explode("Dr.",$temp[2])[1]);
    print_r($temp); 
    //echo "<br/><br/>Name:".$name1[0]." and their value=".$value1;
    //echo "<br/><br/>Name:".$name2[0]." and their value=".$value2;


    $name_str = explode(",",$str);
    //print_r($name_str);
    $name1 = explode(" with",$name_str[1])[0];
    $name2 = explode(" with",$name_str[3])[0];

    echo "<br/><br/>Name:".$name1." and their value=".$value1;
    echo "<br/><br/>Name:".$name2." and their value=".$value2;
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Medical services provided by members of regulated professions Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value [1] => 2000.00 Dr. James Silva with value of [2] => 5000.00 and Dr. Joey House with no value [3] => 6500.00 )

Name: Dr. Rachel G. Barry and their value=2000.00

Name: Dr. James Silva and their value=5000.00
```

Comment: I really tried this way, but is not useful, because sometimes the string don't use the abbreviation dr, sometimes comes like this: Doctor James, Medic James.

Comment: @Bia, Could you please try now, i have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
$str="Medical services provided by members of regulated professions, Dr. Rachel G. Barry with no value $ 4,000.12, Dr. James Silva with value of $ 6,000.90 and Dr. Joey House with no value $ 6,500.00";

preg_match_all('/([\$]|EUR|€)\s*([0-9,\s]*\.?[0-9]{0,2})?+/', $str, $matches);
$match_array = $matches[0];
foreach ($match_array as $key => $value) {

    $pos = strpos($str, $value);
    $pos += strlen($value);
    $output_str =trim(substr($str,0,$pos));
    if($output_str[0] == ",")
        $output_str =preg_replace('/,/', '', $output_str, 1);

    echo $output_str;
    $str= substr($str,$pos);    
    echo "<br>";
}
```